# sql - how to insert on table1 from table2 but dont insert the duplicate value

Tags: sql

i have 2 table, table1 and table2, each of them have rows added table1 = 2m rows and table2 = 1m rows and some rows from table2 is already on table1, and table1 have unique value

i try this command:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (top1, top2, top3)
  SELECT top1, top2, top3 FROM table2
```

top1 is unique value, how i can make the selection so if table2 top1 is already on table1 top1 to pass next?

Comment: What is Pk, just top1 or top1+top2+top3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, and some different databases provide easier methods.  Here's a generic solution with `not exists`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (top1, top2, top3)
SELECT top1, top2, top3 FROM table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    select 1 
    from table1 t1 
    where t1.top1 = t2.top1)
```

---

Another generic option with an `outer join` \ `null` check:

```
insert into table1 (top1, top2, top3)
select t2.top1, t2.top2, t2.top3
from table2 t2 
   left join table1 t1 on t2.top1 = t1.top1
where t1.top1 is null
```